# important piece of user agent

Tags: html, user-agent

How would you represent this user agent string to a directory name.
What information from the user agent is important for the rendering of a page and which is less important. Basically I backed up to disk some websites using the user agent and I'd like to organise them in directories.

```
Browser Identity: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/533+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5
```

I was thinking of naming the above string simply iphone_5.0  is that a good or should it be  iphone_533?

Comment: I find it hard to understand your question, could you rephrase it or add an example? Perhaps some more background?

Comment: Only you know what's important to you. Personally the user-agent of people visiting my sites doesn't matter since I try my best to code in a cross-platform way, so it's all the same.

Comment: Agree. Without more information I'd just say store in however you want, we can't really recommend anything because we don't know the purpose. Are you caching files for specific browsers or something?

Comment: Depends on what information you need. Do you need the name to contain specific data? Which different user agents strings should lead to the same directoryname?

Comment: Chris yes pretty much, we needed an iphone specific version of the site cached to disk

Comment: @user391986, is the cache tied to a specific version of the iPhone? Or is it specific to a flavor of iOS such as iPhone, iPad or iPod? Answer those questions and you'll know the folders to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, but if you want to create a unique directory name for each UA, just put the UA through [`md5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and get something like

```
./sites/example.com/8d4c8e5a685289b8b38b6b7a263c9d83/
```

Answer (score 1):

It really just depends how specific that you want to be. Do you want to know what hardware features the device has? iphone_5 is probably fine. If you want more detail, you might want to include the 533, or even the Safari version. It really depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The history of User-Agent strings is that they are deliberately spoofed. For example, the bit "like Gecko" is deliberately used to coax servers into sending the same markup as it would for Firefox, unless the server knows specifically about Webkit.

The same will continue to happen in the future. If you and others start looking for the string "iPhone", expect other mobile browsers to put "like iPhone" in their User-Agent strings. Make sure you're comfortable with this.